# Can't modify CustomEvent data

Tags: javascript, events

I need to fire a custom event each time when clicked on div with different data attached.

Here is a simplified variant of my code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4VQ/)):

```
<div onclick="selectItem(Math.random())">click me</div>

<script>
function selectItem(id) {
    var event_data = {
        myid: id
    };

    if (!arguments.callee.event)
        arguments.callee.event = new CustomEvent("selectItem", {detail: event_data});

    arguments.callee.event.detail = event_data; // no success here

    document.dispatchEvent(arguments.callee.event);
}

document.addEventListener("selectItem", function(event) {
    console.log(event.detail); // same thing all the time :(
});
</script>
```

But in the event listener function I receive the same data each time the event is fired. I tried to change the event before `dispatchEvent` but seems it is read only object.

Is there any other options to send different data each time i click on div?

Comment: Might be worth using your JS console to see if your browser is returning *actual* random numbers each time - we had a problem recently where IE (and I think FF) were not as random as Chrome/Safari

Comment: in console I see that it returns same number every time, in Chrome and Firefox, so I think it is not a problem with specific browser

Comment: @artnikpro if it's returning the same number each time, isn't this what's causing your error to receive the same data each time?

Comment: @PSL Why do I need to create a new event each time? And actually I already tryed to do that, but it becomes much worse. The event becomes  to fire via fold

Comment: @adam, yes, this is an issue I need to fix

Comment: @artnikpro i.e because detail is readonly . See this http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#attributes-1

Comment: @artnikpro You want to add data to event you can just do this way: http://jsfiddle.net/uW5jm/ Detail property, i believe, is specifically set to specify detail regarding the event, so there no reason for it to change when it is dispatched each time and hence they are readonly and can be set when you create it for the first time alone.

Comment: @artnikpro Do you want me to post it as answer...

Comment: @PSL, yeah sure, I wanna vote! ;)

Comment: @artnikpro Which FF version? Seems to be working for me in FF.

Comment: @PSL, no-no it's OK! Just Firebug bug, it does not shows it when i do `console.log(event)` but with `console.log(event.data)` is all good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that [detail property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#attributes-1) of the event can be any object but they are read only, i.e they can be set only when the event is created.Iit is specifically used to provide details regarding the event, and not for attaching data for each dispatch of the event.

> interface CustomEvent {
> readonly    attribute any detail;
> };

Probably you can just set a custom property `data` to the event during each dispatch and access that property.

Try:

```
function selectItem(id) {
        var event_data = {
            myid: id
        };

        if (!arguments.callee.event) arguments.callee.event = new CustomEvent("selectItem");;
        arguments.callee.event.data = event_data; 

        document.dispatchEvent(arguments.callee.event);
    }

    document.addEventListener("selectItem", function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V3dnT/)**

Or you would need to init the custom Event each time to set the details property like this:

```
arguments.callee.event.initCustomEvent("selectItem", true, true, event_data);
```

and `details` property will have new updated value each time the event is dispacthed.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LLthC/)**

Comment: Note that `initCustomEvent` is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/initCustomEvent#browser_compatibility) and should not be used.