# Angular Typescript: How to pass data to CustomEvent in Jasmine test

Tags: angular, events, jasmine

The answer to this similar question appears to be out-of-date.
[Can't modify CustomEvent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316963/cant-modify-customevent-data)

I am writing a jasmine test where I am trying to pass in data.

In the actual application when the onSelect event is emitted to listening function,

```
console.log('here', JSON.stringify(evt))
```

shows the data to be as expected. For Example:

```
{ "id" : "31", "date_inserted" : "2018-05-12T13:36:32" }
```

However, when I write my jasmine test, I am unable to pass in data in a CustomEvent. Some research indicates "detail" is a read-only property.

The code fragment below gets an HTML element which has an onSelect listener attached. Console.log triggers as expect, however the only thing that is ever returns is {"isTrusted":false}

```
it('should see the data' () => {
    const myButton = nativeElement.querySelector('#myButton');
    expect(myButton).not.toBeNull();
    myButton.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('onSelect', {"detail: {"foo": "bar"}});
});
```

There's gotta be a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FINALLY worked out how to do this.

For whatever reason, the javascript version of doing this as kindly suggested by Alex doesn't seem to work in jasmine testing for typescript.

What DOES work is the following:

```
const selectEvent: any = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
selectEvent.id = '1';
selectEvent.initEvent('onSelect', true, true);
myButton.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
```

Comment: Yes. The difference that in this case you do not use prototype, but assign properties directly. The reason is just in JSON.stringify() behavior. You also can use initial implementation, but check data directly, like expect(event.id).toEqual(1) instead of using JSON.stringify

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()` stringifies only own properties. Everything that in the prototype - not being stringified. Try to address directly to required data.

For example usual `'resize'` event shows `'{"isTrusted":true}'` when execute `JSON.stringify(e)`. But contains all required data

[image]

Comment: Sorry...that was a typo on my part in the question being asked. In the compiler itself if the bracket would have been missing, it would have complained. :) Thanks for noticing!